# Javascript Object forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

Hi Im trying to access the child nodes of a selected  element, but the browser tells me that that object doesn't have a foreach function. What should I do for me to access the child elements. I dont want to use jquery instead I want to use native, for experiment purpose.

here is my code:

```js
var el = document.querySelector('ol');
el.children.forEach(function(childEl) {
  console.log(childEl);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ol contenteditable oninput="">
    <li>press enter</li>
  </ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `foreach` is not valid function, use `forEach` *Capital E*, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @Tushar nope it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Node.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) is  [dom collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an real array so it doesn't have array methods like `forEach`(need to fix the case also).

So one commonly used solution is to call the array methods with the context as the html collection

```js
var el = document.querySelector('ol');
[].forEach.call(el.children, function(childEl) {
  console.log(childEl);
})
```

```html
  <ol contenteditable oninput="">
    <li>press enter</li>
  </ol>
```

---

Another way(similar) is to convert the collection to an array first(using Array.slice()) then call array methods on it

```js
var el = document.querySelector('ol'),
  array = [].slice.call(el.children);
array.forEach(function(childEl) {
  console.log(childEl);
})
```

```html
<ol contenteditable oninput="">
  <li>press enter</li>
</ol>
```